# How to make youtube-dl support non ASCII characters?

Tags: python, youtube-dl

When downloading videos from youtube using youtube-dl everything works as it should except one thing, If the file name contains non english charachters like accented e or arabic charachters etc. they are completed skipped.

Ex: "Stromae - ta fête" would be downloaded with file name "Stromae - ta fte"

Kindly advise what changes should I make to support such charachters in the filename.

Comment: what is the system encoding? what does `locale` output?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I think thats the problem, how can I change it to UTF8 ?

Comment: try this first `export LC_ALL=en_ZW.utf8` or whatever is appropriate for your locale

Comment: @PadraicCunningham 
Ran `export LC_ALL=en_US.utf8` under both root and apache and rebooted the server, still the issue persists under apache. What now ?

Comment: you did not reboot before you tried the code again?

Comment: You should no reboot, the change will be lost. Run the export command from bash then run the python code from that shell

Comment: But even after reboot I can see the setting is changed. By the way It already works under root but not apache.

Comment: You should not be able to see it, exporting only lasts as long as the terminal is open. what does locale output? without the `-a` for both root and apache?

Comment: ok then `export LC_ALL=LANG=en_US.UTF-8` in bash then try running the code from bash

Comment: Why do you want me to do it in bash ? I already mentioned that it works in bash as root. I ran this `<?php system('export LC_ALL=LANG=en_US.UTF-8'); system('youtube-dl https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fatfDUPiJ5U'); ?>` Still not working :(

Comment: You need to set the locale for apache, there is no way it is going work until the locale is set to utf-8. add the following in  in  `/etc/default/locale` ` `LANG=en_US.UTF-8"`
`LANGUAGE="en_US:en"`, logout/reboot and try again, make sure to check the locale after.

Comment: Thank you! now It is works fine in bash for both root and apache, but when I try using php, the same old issue exists. Can you help me with that ? I already tried `setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US.UTF-8");`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78262/discussion-between-kazi-lotus-and-padraic-cunningham).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having never used youtube-dl, I can't say for sure, but it may not be youtube-dl that is removing non-ascii characters.  You'll notice their documentation has an option for removing non-ascii characters from filenames, though it doesn't appear to be the default:

https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl#filesystem-options

It could be that your operating system doesn't allow non-ascii characters and is removing them.  Can you save other files with ascii characters?

Comment: I just tried it on my laptop (ubuntu 15.04) and my pc (windows 8.1), Both of them worked perfectly, no issues whatsoever. I am now sure the problem isn't with the program but my server (Ubuntu 14.04), What do you think could cause this ?

Comment: Don't know - wish I could help there.  By default Ubuntu 14 allows non-ascii file names.  I assume it's either some setting on your server - or perhaps your server is using a version of Python that doesn't agree with youtube-dl.

Comment: I tried downloading again on my server as root user and it works just as it should, then i tried to save a file on system with accented e using php, the file saves but the e is skipped, so probably something is wrong with apache I guess. What can I do now ?

Answer (score 0):

**It worked for my using Python 3.6 instead of 2.7**

Using Python 2.7 y get the following message when trying to download some videos:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2013' in position 76: ordinal not in range(128)
```

With Python 3.6 I get the video downloaded without entering any extra parameters.